# slickgrid column resizable option not working/ how to adjust slick grid column with mouse pointer

Tags: slickgrid

I am trying to adjust column with mouse pointer in a grid generated
i have enabled resizable option in every column
but column is not adjustable with mouse pointer

but the examples given in slickgrid. column is adjustable

how to i make my grid column adjustable. (i verified in chrome browser)

Comment: have you provided any min-width and max-width value? If both are same you cannot resize obviously...

Comment: no min-width and max-width value given

Comment: ok...can you upload your code to js fiddle and share the link

Comment: var ctrlpcfields = [
            { id: "Options", name: "Options", field: "Options", width: 70, formatter: Slick.Formatters.MgrOption, sortable: true },
            {                
                id: "Alias", name: "Alias", field: "Alias", width: 150, sortable: true

Comment: your column settings seems fine...can u see the resize image of cursor when u take your cursor over column border. Also inspect the column to check whether its a z-index issue.

Comment: whether (missing/in visibility) of any supporting file may cause nonworking of reside column dragging.. i suspect so. whats your opinion

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with using outerWidth for setting the column's previous width. Changing

```
columnElements.each(function (i, e) {
  columns[i].previousWidth = $(e).outerWidth();
});
```

to

```
columnElements.each(function (i, e) {
  columns[i].previousWidth = $(e).width();
});
```

in slickgrid in the function setupColumnResize() in the .dragstart bind should work.

Comment: This will cause some weird jumpiness when dragging. It should actually be `$(e).outerWidth(false)`

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid has already set default column options in slick.grid.js. The default column options is set like below.

```
var columnDefaults = {
  name: "",
  resizable: true,
  sortable: false,
  minWidth: 30,
  rerenderOnResize: false,
  headerCssClass: null,
  defaultSortAsc: true
};
```

If you still got error, please upload your code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and share the link.